# Having an active state on a link while on another page

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink

So I want to know how to allow a link to be active with a style even if it is on another page.

You would click on a link in the nav bar, but inside that specific link is a page that is not in the nav bar, but still keep the active state on the first clicked link.

```
<a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'products.php')) echo 'class="activeb"';?> href="products.php">PRODUCTS
</a>
```

But I want another page thas not the nav bar to still have the link styled with this class.
Can it be done?

The css

```
.activeb{
    padding: 0 0 15px 0 !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Sorry about poor description. First timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("a[href='"+location.pathname.substring(1)+"']").addClass('activeb')
```

---

Using `a[href="product.php"]` as a jquery selector will select all links with product.php

To dynamically produce the current link, in your format, I used `location.pathname` (`/product.php`) and removed the beginning slash `.substring(1)` and finally, used `addClass('activeb')`